# Notepad++ NppFTP alternative in linux

Tags: server, plugins, webserver, websites

I know there are questions about notepad++ here but mine is a bit different. I am developing a website and with the NppFTP plugin in Notepad++ I am able to directly connect to the server that contains the site I am working on. I am able to create/edit/delete pages/content etc. Is there something similiar in Linux. Any tool that will let me edit pages directly on the server. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs and the Tramp extension does that and more.  It supports ssh, sftp and the old insecure ftp extension. And yes, it works like editing the file locally.  No need to anything extra installed.
Just open the file like this in Emacs: `C-x` `C-f` `/user@machine:/path/to/file`

But if you are serious working with a website or something like that, you should use a version control system like git or subversion.  So when you want to put the data on the server, you just check it out from the repository into the server.  That allows you to make lots of tests, and always back upp to previous version if it doesn't work.  Even work on many different versions at the same time.

Yes, Emacs have good support for many different version controll systems too.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text with Ftpsync plugin. https://github.com/NoxArt/SublimeText2-FTPSync or

[Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp)(paid)

2 Install curlftpfs and use this to mount ftp site locally.

```
sudo apt-get install curlftpfs
```

Let's say here's the detail

My ftp User: surendra_a

My ftp password: redhat

My ftp Server: ftp2.linuxnix.com

My mount point: /ftpmount

Now create the mount point and mount ftp account data.

```
mkdir /ftpmount
 curlftpfs -o allow_other surendra_a:redhat@ftp2.linuxnix.com /ftpmount
```

This way you can use any text editor.

More details [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/03/mount-ftp-server-linux.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just use nautilus to connect to the server, then you can use any program that you like to edit those files.

To connect to the server, open the file manager (Nautilus), hit CTRL+L and type in the bar the server address (somthing like ftp://ftp.server.com). A window will open asking for an user name and a password. Afterwards the remote folder will appear on the left bar and you can use any program to save or edit files in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jEdit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jedit)[image: Install jEdit] with the FTP plugin.

jEdit FTP Plugin description:

```
The FTP plugin plugs into jEdit's virtual filesystem to allow transparent access to 
(S)FTP servers. It integrates with the filesystem browser (hence you can do things like 
add favorites which point to remote servers, and such), caches remote directory listings 
for improved performance, remembers passwords, and has optional support for passive-mode 
FTP.

In addition, when running on Java 2 version 1.5, the FTP plugin can edit and browse files 
stored on SFTP servers.
```

[jEdit Website](http://www.jedit.org/)